# How do I set \itemsep to rubber length?

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize, lengths

I know that I can set `\itemsep` to any length like this,

```
\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
```

But if I want to set `\itemsep` to a rubber length (e.g. `\bigskip`), how do I do this?

```
\setlength{\itemsep}{\bigskip}
```

does not work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The skip is `\bigskipamount`; `\bigskip` is a `\vskip` of `\bigskipamount`, so you could use

```
 \setlength{\itemsep}{\bigskipamount}
```

Of course, you can say

```
 \setlength{\itemsep}{12pt plus4pt minus4pt}
```

For the record, the definitions in Plain:

```
\newskip\smallskipamount % the amount of a \smallskip
\smallskipamount=3pt plus1pt minus1pt
\newskip\medskipamount % the amount of a \medskip
\medskipamount=6pt plus2pt minus2pt
\newskip\bigskipamount % the amount of a \bigskip
\bigskipamount=12pt plus4pt minus4pt

\def\smallskip{\vskip\smallskipamount}
\def\medskip{\vskip\medskipamount}
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}
```

and in the LaTeX kernel:

```
\def\smallskip{\vspace\smallskipamount}
\def\medskip{\vspace\medskipamount}
\def\bigskip{\vspace\bigskipamount}

\newskip\smallskipamount 
\smallskipamount=3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
\newskip\medskipamount
\medskipamount =6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt
\newskip\bigskipamount
\bigskipamount =12pt plus 4pt minus 4pt
```